# Power Automate Delivers Corrupted Files/PDFs - but Sharepoint files work fine

Tags: power-automate

I have created a series of Power Automate Flows that connect with Microsoft Forms; many of them have multiple attachment requirements. When the form is submitted, the files are successfully parsed into the correct folders in the form's Sharepoint directory/directories, and the files work properly there. On the Power Automate side, however, only the first attachment goes through successfully; the others throw error messages like this:

[Adobe Acrobat Failure alert: Acrobat could not open file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhLA7.png)

As the form is organizational, I'm grabbing the user profile to populate some of the areas.

The schema for the JSON parse is:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {},
            "size": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "referenceId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "driveId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "uploadSessionUrl": {}
        },
        "required": []
    }
}
```

Here's the full automation with sensitive information redacted:

[Power Automate Flow 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbXvo.png)

[Power Automate Flow 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io46Q.png)

It would be much appreciated if someone could clarify why this is happening and how to correct it. We have people who work with the emails to process the paperwork and do/should not have access to Sharepoint, so other staff are supply the files by downloading them from their site.